# Generic GDI+ Error on image.save

Tags: c#, image, gdi+

I've been fighting this for over an hour. I have read this error is generally because the MemoryStream gets closed before the bitmap gets disposed, but in here I'm not disposing of anything. Any help would be appretiated.

```
 public Image GetImageFromBytes(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
       var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
       return Image.FromStream(ms);
    }        

    public void ExportImage(byte[] imageBytes, String fileName)
    {
        var image = GetImageFromBytes(imageBytes);
        //  var resizedImg = GeneralHelper.ResizeImage(image,ImageWidth, ImageHeight) ;
        //  OverlayContactDetails(resizedImg);

        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);


        image.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    }
```

The exception is thrown while .Save()-ing (as the title suggests). Below is the stack trace

```
  at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at AdCreator.ImageExport.ExportImage(Byte[] imageBytes, String fileName) in c:\Users\Paavum Ex Machina\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AdCreator\AdCreator\ImageExport.cs:line 70
   at AdCreator.ExportController.ExportImage(Byte[] image, String filePath, String agentText) in c:\Users\Paavum Ex Machina\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AdCreator\AdCreator\ExportController.cs:line 69
   at AdCreator.ExportController.Export(String outputFilename) in c:\Users\Paavum Ex Machina\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AdCreator\AdCreator\ExportController.cs:line 44
   at AdCreator.Controller.ExportAds(Ad[] ads, String[] templates, String outputFileName) in c:\Users\Paavum Ex Machina\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AdCreator\AdCreator\Controller.cs:line 104
   at AdCreator.Create.<>c__DisplayClass3.<button2_Click>b__1() in c:\Users\Paavum Ex Machina\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AdCreator\AdCreator\Create.cs:line 173
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: What about the stacktrace? at which line it throws the exception?

Comment: This will fail the *second* time you save to the same filename.  You must dispose the image to release the lock on the file.  Use the *using* statement on the *image* variable.

Comment: @HansPassant: This actually fails every single time. Just tried the using and I get the exact same error :s

Comment: Looking at the image with some sort of image viewer can certainly do this as well.  I can only see what you are obviously doing wrong.

Comment: @DavidSarmiento are you sure the `filename` does not exist?

Comment: @KingKing I'm positive.

Comment: @HansPassant: The byte array is a valid image, I can see the image with a MySQL Client when looking at the field where the byte data is stored

Comment: @DavidSarmiento try looking in the `Inner Exception` and see what it is.

Comment: @KingKing a very helpful null :s

Comment: @DavidSarmiento now don't try saving your image to file after getting it from `GetImageFromBytes`, just try showing it such as in a `PictureBox` to see if you can see it?

Comment: @KingKing The image shows ok

Comment: @DavidSarmiento now I'm almost sure that you encountered some IO exception but it's not exposed, it should be exposed as the Inner Exception.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41828/discussion-between-david-sarmiento-and-king-king)

Comment: I cannot spot any concrete reason for this error. This code is not error-prone. Maybe your machine is hosed. Try a different image format. Maybe the Jpeg code is botched.

Comment: @usr tried changing teh format to png and same error

Comment: Create a console application consisting just of the very few lines that cause the error. Open a Windows pre-installed image like "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Nature\img1.jpg" and save it to a hard-coded path. Can you still reproduce the issue? If yes your machine is definitely hosed.